# In a single expression, why does multiple uses of object() return different or same id?

Tags: python

I'm on python 3.10

- `id(object()),id(object())` returns `(4519407312, 4519407312)` (Exact id is not important)
- `object() is object()` returns `False`

Why do the `object()` in second expression contain different id while the `object()` in first expression has same id?

**Context**

This question was inspired by me noticing coding patterns of using object as a sentinel when None has some special meaning making it unusable.

I wanted to check whether any object from the import could cause `if possibly_overwritten is not _UNDEFINED:` to fail wrongly. That happens when id() of the value overwriting `possibly_overwritten` is the same as id of `_UNDEFINED`, which the first expression above demonstrated.

```
_UNDEFINED = object()
possibly_overwritten = _UNDEFINED

# may assign a value to possibly_overwritten
from local_config import *

if possibly_overwritten is not _UNDEFINED:
   ...
```

Comment: In your first example, the two instances of `object()` *did not exist at the same point in time* - they were eligible for garbage-collection after you applied `id()` to them - and the second one *might* (this is not guaranteed) be reallocated at the same address as the first one.  Any program that cares about this, one way or the other, is utterly broken.

Comment: @jasonharper Could you expand on the point in time concept? In my understanding, all objects exist simultaneously as long as memory allows until the REPL environment is closed or the python interpreter completes running a script. 
How does wrapping an id() cause object() to be eligible for garbage-collection? 
What is the simplest thing i can do to make it not eligible for garbage-collection?

My guess is it's garbage-collected because reference counter is 0 because object() isn't bound to a variable, but second expression also had no assignment to variable, so doesn't seem right.

Comment: Being assigned to a variable isn't the only way to keep an object alive - it could be an element of a list or other container, or a parameter to a function call that's currently in progress.  In your second example, both `object()`s obviously have to exist at the same time in order for them both to be passed to the `is` operator.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks I read your comment `after you applied id() to them` again and understand now.  

I removed id() and found a simple way `object(),object()` to create 2 different objects `(<object at 0x10d60ae30>, <object at 0x10d60ac80>)`.

Previously, I saw `id(object())` as a single unit of execution. but i should see `id()` as an extra operation, and the 1st `object()` (evaluating expressions in tuples left to right) is no longer needed after going through the first `id()`, before creating the 2nd `object()`

Answer (score 0):

This is because Python reuses the same object instance for performance reasons.

Check this out:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
b.append(4)
```

You will see that `a = [1,2,3,4]`

That means `b=a` is not really copying the object (the list in our case), but is something like a referral.

if you want really to copy `a` to `b` and use them like different lists, you should check `copy()` and `deepcopy()`